# How to set ip of an container accessible from host / solve redirect problem caused by keycloak in docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, single-sign-on, keycloak, grafana

I need to solve the problem of redirection in docker-compose using either static IP addresses visible from the host or another method. I am trying to deploy 2 solutions, namely grafana and keycloak. Unfortunately, if I use standard port mapping to localhost in the redirection process keycloak tries to redirect to grafana container, which cannot be accessed by the host as DNS won't solve the name. Is there a way to assign said addresses to the container in a way that would solve this problem or allow containers to be accessed from localhost altogether. (I have tires network_mode: host) but this approach doesn't work on Windows 10 and has many other problems.
Exemplary docker file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
 keycloak:
   build: ./keycloak/
   container_name: keycloak
   ports:
     - "8180:8180"
 grafana:
   image: bitnami/grafana:latest
   container_name: grafana
   ports:
     - 3000:3000
   volumes:
     - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/opt/bitnami/grafana/conf/grafana.ini
```

Here is my grafana config:

```
[server]
# Protocol (http, https, h2, socket)
;protocol = http

http_port = 3000

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
;domain = localhost

# Redirect to correct domain if host header does not match domain
# Prevents DNS rebinding attacks
;enforce_domain = false

# The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
# If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
;root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
root_url = http://host.docker.internal:3000/

[auth]
# Login cookie name
login_cookie_name = grafana_session


#################################### Generic OAuth ##########################
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
name = Keycloack
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = grafana
scopes = openid email profile
auth_url = http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_url = http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
api_url = http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
client_secret = secret
role_attribute_path = contains(info.groups[*], 'admin') && 'Admin' || contains(info.groups[*], 'editor') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'
```

The rest is default.

I have tried all variations of localhost keycloak and grafana possible, with no results whatsoever.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you are trying to access grafana from the keycloack container you should use grafana:3000. If you are trying to access it from the host, then use localhost:3000

Comment: It's not that simple. When I access grafana from localhost then I get redirected to keycloak after verification I get redirected to grafana:3000 as the request came from this container. as I cannot access the container by its name as the network isn't available from the host.

Comment: Please show your Grafana config.